# VBA Copy row and column headers which has specific values

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to Visual basic, I have an excel sheet in the following format as shown in the image below.

[image: Excel Format]

I need to write a VB code to create a spreadsheet in the format as shown in the image below. The model name should be printed for every country that has row and column value '1' in the excel sheet. In other words just need to print Model name and Country name that has value '1' in the spreadsheet. If the cell is empty or value '0' then we need not print the model name for that particular country.

[image: Final Format]

How do I go about it? I have been watching videos to do this but to no avail.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Edited: The current output after using the below code is in this screenshot

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work smoothly, it will created a new sheet at every run to display the output! ;)

```
Sub test_Dazzler()

Dim wB As Workbook, _
    wBNeW As Workbook, _
    wSSrC As Worksheet, _
    wSDesT As Worksheet, _
    LastRow As Long, _
    LastCol As Integer, _
    WrintingRow As Long, _
    ModeL As String

Set wB = ThisWorkbook
Set wSSrC = wB.ActiveSheet
LastRow = wSSrC.Range("A" & wSSrC.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = wSSrC.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
Set wSDesT = wB.Sheets.Add
wSDesT.Cells(1, 1) = "Model": wSDesT.Cells(1, 2) = "Countries"

With wSSrC
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ModeL = .Range("A" & i).Value
        For j = 2 To LastCol
            If .Cells(i, j) <> 1 Then
            Else
                WrintingRow = wSDesT.Range("A" & wSDesT.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                wSDesT.Cells(WrintingRow, 1) = ModeL
                wSDesT.Cells(WrintingRow, 2) = .Cells(1, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    DoEvents
    WsDest.Copy
End With
Set wBNeW = ActiveWorkbook

Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String

'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
'determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    'get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
    If strPath <> False Then wBNeW.SaveAs strPath
    'displays the result in a message box
    Call MsgBox(strPath, vbInformation, "Save Path")
End If

MsgBox "I'm done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @R3uK, thank you very much for the answer. I tried it and I am only able to create new column headers. Can I know how to display the values in the cells?

Comment: What is the output that you have with this? Can you post a screenshot? I didn't get what you mean with your comment sorry...

Comment: Sorry for inadequate information in the above comment. I have added the output I got in the last part of the question (3rd Screenshot) for your reference. As displayed above I am able to get only Model and country but with no values under it. Can you please let me know how do I get values as mentioned in 2nd screenshot in the question?

Comment: As I don't know the name of your initial sheet's screenshot, I set the "data" sheet as the active sheet so in order to get this code to work, you need to be on the initial sheet before launching the code. Or you can change the line `Set wSSrC = wB.ActiveSheet` to `Set wSSrC = wB.Sheets ("NameOfYourSheet")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried doing what you told just now but still getting the same output. Been trying to get this to work all day but no luck. Is there any other way around this? The name of my Initial sheet is "TransposedPivotValues" so I changed it to `Set wSSrC = wB.Sheets ("TransposedPivotValues")`, hope that's correct. Please let me know if its wrong.

Comment: You've done good on your part, so it seems that there is another issue. Most probably the test `If .Cells(i,j)<>1 Then`, do you know how to debug? If you can put a breakpoint on this line to see what is the detected value of `.Cells(i,j)`

Comment: I added the breakpoint to that line, It appears that if loop isn't executed. After `ModeL = .Range("A" & i).Value For j = 2 To LastCol` the control is going to `Next i` instead of entering the loop. Any idea how to fix this? Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: What is the value of `LastCol`?

Comment: You are a legend @R3uK. It works perfectly fine :) Thanks a ton for your help on this. Really appreciate it alot :)

Comment: Can I please know how to copy the Model and countries into another workbook? As in, the same procedure what you are doing now but instead of copying into a new sheet, can we copy and paste it into another workbook and name that workbook? Would be really helpful if you could help me out or any references would be helpful. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: I added the code to create a copy of the generated sheet and export it into a new workbook! ;)

Comment: thanks a lot :) will try it out and let u know :) thanks again ;)

Comment: I tried the above code. I am getting a compiler error: Can't assign to readonly property for the line `wbNew.Name = "Name of the file". after a bit of research everywhere it suggested I use SaveAs. Can I please know how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply yesterday I tried the above code and the generated workbook is having the source worksheet contents (1st screenshot). The source workbook is adding extra sheets containing 2nd screenshot. I tried it multiple times the source worksheet is being copied to the destination workbook. I am very sorry for the trouble, but I am not able to fix this hence asking for your help. Please let me know

Comment: I really really need your help, i am very sorry for bugging you. But I tried fixing the problem and the above code is copying the source worksheet into the new workbook rather than destination worksheet. I tried researching and was unable to fix it. Can you please help me? Would be really helpful.

Comment: Is this OK? If not please explain what is happend and what you want to happen.

Comment: I tried the above code, and I ll explain the problem in detail. 
Current scenario - the code is copying the 1st screenshot (source worksheet) to the new workbook.
I wanted to copy the contents of worksheet we are generating (2nd screenshot, `wDesT As Worksheet`) to a new workbook and open save as dialog box.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Its working perfectly fine. You literally saved me :) I am very sorry for bugging you regarding this. My apologies.

Comment: last doubt. What if I want to directly create a new workbook and then display the (2nd screenshot) in the new workbook rather than adding a new worksheet in the source workbook(1st screenshot). Should I just simply set a new workbook as activeworkbook or is that not possible?